# Android Studio, Sync Issue : unable to find DestinationRootCopySpec

Tags: java, android, gradle, synchronization

I've seen many sync issues, tried all the solutions (in settings etc.) I could see but it still says "Sync failed : editing, debugging will not work." At the bottom in gradle messages it states

> Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DestinationRootCopySpec.addFirst()Lorg/gradle/api/internal/file/copy/DefaultCopySpec;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

It's a newly installed windows system, Android Studio never been installed before, (have used eclipse before).

As mentioned I've tried many solutions to similar issues but still cannot clear this error.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I have same problem, looking for a solution now!